# JUnit Testing POST to a parameterized API

Tags: java, junit, mockmvc, web-api-testing

How can I pass {service} to this JUnit test?

```
@Test
public void test4() throws Exception {
    List<ProofOfDeliveryUndeliveredResult> returnList = new ArrayList<ProofOfDeliveryUndeliveredResult>();
    given(undeliveredQueryManager.prepareUndeliverServiceRecords(isA(UndeliveredRetrieveFilters.class),isA(String.class))).willReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().body(returnList));
    String response = server.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/{service}/retrieve").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content("{\"startRetrieveTime\":\"\",\"endRetrieveTime\":\"\",\"timeStampFormat\":\"\"}"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn()
        .getResponse()
        .getContentAsString();
    assertEquals(response,"[]"); 
}
```

Comment: /api/{service}/retrieve - means your controller expects any service path param.
If you have logic behind this service param, so you can specify any desired service, something like:
/api/desiredService/retrieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `post()` method of `MockMvcRequestBuilders` allows you to pass a variable list of parameters, see the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html). The provided parameters are replaced into the URL in order.

```
server.perform(
  MockMvcRequestBuilders
    .post("/api/{service}/retrieve", "someservice")
    .contentType(MediaTy...
```